# Looking for sport tournament software

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a tournament software for Ubuntu/GNU Linux. Badminton. Enter players, system. Not using anything at the moment, but looking for something. Sport Software [link](http://www.sport-software.de/home.html)

Through wine I managed to install and run: [Tournament Planner](http://www.tournamentsoftware.com/product/home.aspx?s=2)

Comment: What sorts of tournaments? What sorts of features? Are there any comparable programs you're using for other operating systems?

Comment: Badminton. Enter players, system. Not using anything at the moment, but looking for something. Sport Software [link](http://www.sport-software.de/home.html)

Answer (score 2):

Something might exist but this strikes me a as pretty niche market.

Small markets mean there's a much lower chance of there being decent software to cater for it. Any development that does happen tends to happen online where developers can ensure they get some sort of kick-back.

If you can't find a desktop app, you might want to try turning to the web. There are a few websites that claim to help solve problems like organising community teams and events, though you may have to do tournaments manually in Inkscape.

- http://sportmeets.com/features
- http://www.schport.com (currently down)

Annoyingly I've also lost a link to another site like the sportmeets site that did look interesting... But you get the idea. There are sites out there that come close to doing what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also searching for this. There is a few, but none that offers all I need. Take a look at http://www.liga-manager-online.de/. Or OSFO (for football tournaments) https://launchpad.net/osfo.

Comment: Please improve your answer by writing part of asnwer here not just links(links may go down later)